Integration of straight line passing through origin with slope $m=1$ with definite integrals formula.
Consider the straight line $y=x$, which passes through the origin and slope $m=1$.
Since slope $m =1$, $\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x = 1$.
When integrating back
$$\int \mathrm{d}x,$$
we get $y=x$.
But when integrating with upper and lower limits like
$$\int_a^b \mathrm{d}x,$$
we get $(b-a)$ as result.
And to get the area below the curve $y=x$, we have to integrate like
$$\int_a^b x \, \mathrm{d}x$$
Based on this, my understanding is that when we differentiate and integrate again, we get the equation of curve/line back. To get the area below the curve, we have to use the equation of the line as $f(x)$ or $y$ in our example (i.e. $x$)
$$\int_a^b x \, \mathrm{d}x$$
to find the area between $x=a$ and $x=b$
or
$$\int_0^a x \, \mathrm{d}x$$
to find the area between $x =0$ and $x= a$.
But what does the result $(b-a)$ mean when we integrate with definite integrals, as shown below?
$$\int_a^b \, \mathrm{d}x$$

length of the segment $a\to b$

In graphical perspective, it gives the area of the rectangle of length $a$ to $b$ or $b - a$, and of width, $1$. Your integral can also be represented as $\int_{a}^{b}{1\cdot dx}$. So the integrand is just a straight line, and you are finding the area under it, which corresponds to a rectangle.

The relation between areas and antiderivatives is the fundamental theorem of calculus, basically $\int_a^b f'(x) d x = f(b) - f(a)$.

@Gribouillis, just to confirm in the formula you have given, the area we are finding is below the curve f '(x) . It is not the area below the curve f(x) which was obtained as anti-derivative from your formula. Am I getting right?

My question may be basic as I am beginner.

@ayyappanmuthukrishnan Yes it is the algebraic area between the curve of $f'$ and the $x$ axis.

@Gribouillis, followed by that I have another doubt. we have a property
$$\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$
so if f(x) = 1 then f(a+b-x)= a+b-1. Is it right?
by having so $$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ evalutes to b-a
and $$\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx = (-a-b+x)\mid_a^b$$; and it results to -a-b-(b-a)=-2b.
if I am right the above property of definite integral is not valid. Where I am making wrong.

I found my mistake $$(-a-b+x)\mid_a^b$$ should be expanded as $$(-a-b+b) - (-a-b+a)$$ so it will come as $$(b-a)$$.
and also when $$f(x) = 1= x^0$$ and $$f(a+b-x)$$ will be equal to $$(a+b-x)^0$$

This question can be marked as closed or solved by moderator as I don't see the option with my login.
